# Is there a good library for sorting a large array of numbers in C?

Tags: sorting, comparison, quicksort, radix-sort

If I have a large array of integers or floats, what is a good algorithm/
implementation for sorting (in C)?

It is a bit late in the game for an edit... but I am looking for correctness and *speed*.

Comment: -1 because based on your comments you really shouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: The faq indicates this is welcome by the company founders... though it also notes that it annoys some users.  But really, I hope to learn something by doing this.  For example, if somebody else has gone through the trouble of customizing/optimizing sorts for each of the C numeric types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sorting arrays of numbers, consider a radix sort algorithm.  When properly engineered, these sorts should provide better performance than GLIBC qsort().

The usort library contains type-specific implementations for all the major C numeric types.

https://github.com/setjmp/usort

The speed advantage of radix sort over GLIBC qsort is about 2.5x for double precision floating  point numbers at N=1000000 on my 64 bit intel laptop.  However, as N grows the advantage should be even greater since radix sort is a linear time algorithm requiring constant number of passes through the data.

For very small N, the same code dispatches to an introsort or insertion sort.

Comment: Radix sort only works if you have a dense, ideally contiguous, list of numbers to sort. It works great if you have, say, a shuffled deck of cards; not so well if you have a scattered range of numbers with possible duplicates.

Comment: Hi John - 

I don't understand your comment.  The radix sort time is pretty deterministic compared to quicksort/introsort which will vary depending on statistics of the data.  

-A

Comment: Also, I think your examples are reversed.  For shuffled deck I think it is quicksort/introsort that will be faster.

Comment: Ach... I am confusing myself now. It is for sorted deck I would expect quicksort to be faster.  But radix sort should exhibit the less variance in sort time.

Comment: There's no real reason why your radix sort has to be endian-specific.  For example, if you're using 65536 buckets, then (NUMBER & 65535) will always give you the least-significant 16 bits of NUMBER, no matter what the endianness of the hardware.  Endianness only comes into it when you start looking at the underlying representation by type-punning pointers.

Comment: @caf Thanks for pointing that out.  As I re-look at the code I think you might be right.  Unfortunately, I don't have a big endian platform around to test it out on.

Comment: My mistake. What I've always called "radix sorting" is in fact "pigeonhole sorting" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_sort), an algorithm which works *fantastically* for decks of cards.

Answer (score 4):

qsort() from the standard library is a good'un.

The comparison functions would be trivial for these cases:

```
int cmp_int(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const int *ia = a;
    const int *ib = b;

    if (*ia < *ib)
        return -1;

    if (*ia > *ib)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

int cmp_float(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const float *fa = a;
    const float *fb = b;

    if (*fa < *fb)
        return -1;

    if (*fa > *fb)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

(EDIT: The version of these based on subtracting b from a relies on signed overflow behaviour, so it's not a good idea.)

Comment: Very handy and general purpose... but not especially fast; the comparison operation is not inlined.  I wonder if the java quicksort (which I think can use inlineable comparisons) might be more competitive than glibc qsort().

On the other hand, for inlined comparisons, the usort library suggested in my solution includes a general purpose introsort with inlined comparisons. It is general purpose in the sense that the comparisons are defined by macros which the #includer defines.

Comment: @ setjmp... then inline his solution.  It is not hard to inline a function in C

Comment: Function pointer arguments can not get inlined in C; the compiler can not be sure what value the pointer will have at run time.  At least, that is what I found last time I investigated.

Comment: In principle, there's no reason why the C compiler couldn't notice that a particular call to qsort always passes a constant function pointer, and behind the scenes create a magic inlined version of qsort().  I doubt there's any compilers that actually do this though, mostly because it's unlikely that the juice would be worth the squeeze.

Comment: In any case, the overhead of non-inlined comparison is noted in the quicksort literature...  there is a paper by Bentely and McGilroy "Engineering a Sort Function" that documents this.  The USort library also contains test code to compare introsort with inlined comparisons vs GLIBC qsort (using random doubles as input):

{{
N               introsort (secs)   GLIBC (secs)    x-fold speedup
10000000 1.6881            2.837         1.68
}}

I believe the advantage of the introsort comes primarily from inlining (the introsort replaced quicksort in my code only recently).

Comment: There should be a line break after "speedup"... I assumed there would be opportunity to edit after posting to make the markup look good.

Comment: A better test would be using the same sorting implementation, just changing it from inlined comparison to indirected comparison.  Then do it again with a more complicated comparison - like sorting { X , Y , Z } cartesian points by their distance from the origin.

Comment: Agreed.  And I think this is what the Bentley/McGilroy paper does in one of their experments.  My introsort/quicksort implementation differs from the GLIBC qsort implementation in the use of textbook recursion (my version) instead of a very complex iterative representation (GLIBC).

Answer (score 0):

It's never a bad idea to use [qsort](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/qsort.html)... unless you know something about the numbers.

You've tagged with radix sort. How much memory are you prepared to invest? Are the numbers inside a specific range? Do they have properties that makes radix sorting feasible?

Unless you want to use a lot of memory, qsort is a great option.

Comment: I have found that as long as the size of the array is big enough, radix sort will soundly beat qsort.  For those small cases, dispatching to comparison-based sorting (with static comparisons) ensures uniform perform gains against qsort. This is the strategy of the usort implementation. As you suggest... there is memory usage:  double the original array size.  However, with 64 bit machines with enough virtual RAM, this will not be a problem.

Comment: A backtrack... for highly repetitive or presorted data... a comparison-based sorting data may be the better choice.

Comment: How do they perform respectively when the array is close to L2 cache size?

Comment: It depends on the size of the type being sorted.  For signed 8 byte integes, the difference is is the 2.5-3x range.

Answer (score 0):

Given a huge amount of RAM we're getting nowadays, the following set sort is possible: mark the bit in a huge RAM bit array for each number you have, then read them off back by scanning the RAM.  Lots of hardware-specific optimizations can be applied for the mark and scan phases.

Comment: The usort library uses a bucket sort for sorting single byte (signed and unsighed).  This is similar to this idea.  Effectively, sorting bytes can be done at a speed similar to one half of memory bandwidth.